# Can I get module handle from function address on linux?

Tags: linux, ld

Same as Win32:

```
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (LPCTSTR)(void*)(myFunc), &h);
```

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlsym.3.html is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dladdr`. Documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr).

Comment: Very late follow up question: where do I find the "module handle" as returned by `dlopen()` in the information provided by `dladdr()`? In your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451791/get-loaded-address-of-a-elf-binary-dlopen-is-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1&lq=1), you say that  the return value of `dlopen()` is a pointer to `struct link_map`.

Comment: @HJP -- You should ask a new question -- it's free. Explaining _why_ you want to find that handle is likely to also be helpful. Otherwise you may be referred to http://xyproblem.info.

Answer (score 0):

Not *per se*, no; if the symbol was compiled in instead of accessed via `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`, then there is no handle to be returned.  (The handle abstraction only exists to enable `dlsym()` fine control over where it loads symbols from; there is no such control over the original link, except via linker scripts.)  In the normal course of events, an object is simply `open()`ed and `mmap()`ed, other details being hidden within `ld.so` and only accessible indirectly via `RTLD_DEFAULT` and `RTLD_NEXT` parameters to `dlsym()`.  If you are using `dlopen()`, you are expected to keep track of your handles.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I am aware of is to parse the contents of `/proc/self/maps` (and/or perhaps `smaps`) and then use the symbol address to calculate from the boundaries of the mapped `.so` (start and its size) within which mapped module the function lies.

Note: `/proc/self` is a symlink (on Linux) to the current process's (with ID `<pid>`) meta-information, i.e. `/proc/<pid>`.

It's possible there is some programming interface to this very information that you could use.

Edit: Ah, so `dladdr()` would be that interface.

Comment: thank you very much.
this information is very useful.
but it's too lower level.
so I want to try other way to work around.

Comment: `dladdr` provides a *much* better method.

Comment: @Employed Russian: no arguing there. I was pointing out that there may be a programming interface as well, which I was not aware of at the time. And undoubtedly `dladdr()` will make use of this information somehow. You could have edited my answer, for example. Either way, learned something and that's (for me) the most important part.