# How to use a 'for' loop that starts scanning at specific location and iterates over 'scan range' in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I need to scan a range of addresses in linux memory and compare its content in 4 bytes jump, I searched the web and didn't find a helpful implementation.
the function I need to implement should be used in a module I'm trying to do.
anyway, the signature of the function:

```
void scanMemory(int scan_range) {
   // implementation here...
}
```

[image: illustration] I need to scan the range between read func which I know and utsname (starting at utsname)

I found so far:
[C Pointers to scan memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870307/c-pointers-to-scan-memory)
which is using a for loop but not quite as I need.

[Memory pattern scanning on Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336791/memory-pattern-scanning-on-linux-in-c)
here I found the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         if(_compare((unsigned char *)(address + i), (unsigned char *)pattern, mask))
               return (unsigned long)(address + i);
    }
```

but I'm not sure the jumps is just 4 bytes.

I'm looking for ideas or implementation of the `for`-loop i describe above

Comment: What is `scan_range`?

Comment: the range of addresses I need to scan, I get the range by subbing 2 addresses.

Comment: *the range of addresses I need to scan* – Then it should be `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t` and not `int`. And how does your function know where to start?

Comment: The prototype doesn't pass enough information to specify a range of memory to look at, or what to look _for_. You would need to use either a first and last address (and be clear about whether your range includes the last address or not) or you could pass a start address and a size (and you need to be clear about whether the size is in bytes or in 4-byte items, since you say you're looking at 4 bytes at a time.) Then your search function needs to be able to return its findings. All in all, I'd recommend `int* scanMemory(int* address, int size, int pattern)` assuming you're using 4-byte `int`s